# Meteor publish/subscribe issue

Tags: meteor

I am obviously not understanding the publish/subscribe system.

I removed the insecure/autopublish packages.

In my server/publish.js I have:

```
Meteor.publish("profiles", function () {
    return Meteor.users.find({}, {
        profile: 1,
        status: 1,
        services: 0
    });
});
```

In my client/lib/collection.js I have:

```
Meteor.subscribe("profiles");
Profiles = new Mongo.Collection("profiles");
```

Now, what I expected was to have a Profiles collection on the client which only contains the profile and status parts of the user document, and does not contain the services part (which has provate info like email and such).

However, on the client the Profiles collection is empty, while the Meteor.users() is available and has everything in it so that anyone who knows how to open the console can see private data about all users...

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT:** Interestingly, when I remove the publish profiles completely, then on the client side the Meteor.users has only the current user in it and only the `profile` section of it. Now I am totally confused.

Comment: If the user is logged in, no matter what happens, the data will be published on the client( only that user's data). your publish method is working as expected. in a nutshell, user's own data is published automatically by meteor.

Comment: I don't understand your answer? Did you read my question? How is my publish working correctly when a) the Profiles collection is empty on the client and b) the Meteor.users() collection on the client has ALL the client and their private data?

Comment: Meteor.users().find() returns the documents that's subscribed in the client. if you remove autopublish, it's not usual to get the data.you might have some other code which is responsible.

Comment: Seriously, I have no idea what you're talking about...

Comment: okay, maybe i have failed interpret your question. pardon me for these `irrelevant suggestions`

Comment: No problem. Thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 1):

UPS, the Meteor `.find` syntax is a little different from the standard mongodb `.find` syntax. I needed to add the `"fileds"` keyword and then it works as expected.

(*almost, since my Profiles collection is still empty on the client...?*)

```
Meteor.publish("profiles", function () {
    return Meteor.users.find({}, {
        fields: {
            "services": 0
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** Ok, thanks to Thai Tran I finally realized that in fact I DID misunderstand the publish/subscribe system. I wrongly thought the publish "name" on the server is going to be the collection name on the client. Now that I understand how it works it is clear why my Profiles collection is empty.

Comment: Your profile collection is nothing related to your user collection. These are 2 totally different collections. When you publish your data, the root collection will be available on the client side, as in, the user collection. If you want to have the profile collection in your system, you need to change the way to save the user and profile (like one to many relationship in the old database design) and then publish the profile collection based on the user id

Comment: I think I finally understand. I was under the wrong impression that the publish "name" part defines the Collection name which is used on the client, but I see now how and why I had the wrong idea. Thanks!